# Google Analytics Event Image Tag Creation

Tags: image, events, google-analytics, event-tracking

Wondering if someone can help me...
I'm working with an application system that only accepts simple img tags for tracking, they won't take JS or GTM at all.

Is it possible to create these for events, so I can create the necessary goals within Google Analytics?

I have the event like so:

ga('send','event', 'ATS','Application', 'Application Start',0,{'nonInteration':false});

But obviously I need the img part and the UA-ID etc. I'm not great with this stuff and all the documentation I can find relates to email sends, which isn't applicable here.

Also, it's for a page load.

Many thanks for any help!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those reading in the future... This is what ended up working:

<img style = "width: 1%; ; "src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=555&ec=ATS&ea=Application&el=Application%20Start&ni=0"alt=""height="1"/>

I used the hit builder mentioned above: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ (thanks Дмитро Булах) to determine which parameters I needed and added the collect query to tell them to be sent to GA.

I put the cid as 555 to anonymise it (don't know if that was a good idea), then put the whole thing inside an img tag I lifted from somewhere else.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can build up your simple image tag using [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1). You can use handy [Hit builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to populate a necessary event url

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. From that I have this: v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-XXXXXX&ec=ATS&ea=Application&el=Application%20Start ... But how do I get that into a tag? Where do I find the cid?

Comment: usually, cid is a unique browser identifier, like some random value stored in cookie/localStorage. If you don't have access to storage the best practice would be using at least some random value for each hit